# I want to combine two separate pagination models in laravel

Tags: laravel, merge, eloquent, pagination

I want to combine two separate pagination model in laravel, but errors in the view and paging does not work.
my controller code ,I also tried different methods, data comes but paging is not my goal paging

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\News;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Blog;
use App\Models\Company\CompanyEvent;


class NewsController extends Controller
{


    function news()
    {

        $blogs       = Blog::sort()->with('company')->paginate(15);
        $events        = CompanyEvent::sort()->with('company')->paginate(15);


        $events=collect($events)->merge($blogs);

        return view('news.news',compact('events'));
    }


    function detail()
    {
        return "detail";
    }
}
```

blog model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Company\Company;
use App\Models\Interfaces\CreatedAt;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class Blog
 * @package App\Models
 * @mixin Builder
 * @property boolean $active
 * @property  int $company_id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $url
 * @property string $context
 * @property string $tags
 * @property  string $main
 * @property string $seo_title
 * @property string seo_description
 * @property string $seo_keyword
 * @property string $image
 * @property-read CreatedAt|Carbon $created_at
 * @property-read CreatedAt|Carbon $updated_at
 * @property-read CreatedAt|Carbon $deleted_at
 * @method static Builder|Blog find(int $id)
 * @method static Builder|Blog where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
 * @method static Builder|Blog findOrFail($id)
 * @method static Builder|Blog active()
 * @method Builder|Blog filter(Request $request)  bind to scopeFilter method
 * @method static Builder|Blog sort()  laravel query bind to scopeSort  method
 * @method static Builder|Blog latest()  laravel query bind to scopeSort  method
 *
 */
class Blog extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'blogs';


    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isActive(): bool
    {
        return (bool)$this->active;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $save
     * @return bool
     */
    public function toggleActive($save = false)
    {

        $this->active = !$this->active;

        if ($save == true)
            return $this->save();

        return false;
    }


    /**
     * @return MorphToMany
     */
    function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Blog', 'commentable');
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    function getAgoTimeAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->diffForHumans();
    }

    /**
     * @param $value
     * @return array
     *
     */
    function getTagsAsArrayAttribute($value)
    {
        return explode(',', $this->tags);
    }


    /**
     * @param Builder|Blog $query
     * @return mixed
     *
     */
    function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('active', 1);
    }


    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id', 'id');
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    function getTimeAgoAttribute()
    {

        return Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->diffForHumans();
    }


    /**
     * @return false|string
     */
    function getShortContextAttribute()
    {
        return substr($this->context, 0, 250);
    }


    /**
     * @param Blog|Builder $query
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    function scopeFilter($query, $request)
    {

        $requests = $request->except('page');

        foreach ($requests as $key => $val)
            $query = $query->where($key, 'like', '%' . $val . '%');


        return $query;
    }


    /**
     * @param Builder|Blog $query
     * @return mixed
     */
    function scopeSort($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }


}
```

company event model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Company;

use App\Calendar\Day\Day;
use App\Calendar\Month\Month;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

/**
 * Class CompanyEvent
 * @mixin Builder
 * @package App\Models\Company
 * @property \DateTime $date
 * @method static Builder|CompanyEvent get()
 * @method static Builder|CompanyEvent find($id)
 * @method static Builder|CompanyEvent findOrFail($id)
 * @method static Builder|CompanyEvent active()  bind to scopeActive
 * @method static Builder|CompanyEvent sort()
 * @method static Builder|CompanyEvent latest()
 *
 */
class CompanyEvent extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;


    protected $table = 'company_events';


    /**
     * get day name  from date column
     * @return string
     *
     */
    function getDayNameAttribute()
    {
        $dayIndex = (int)date('w', strtotime($this->date));
        return ucfirst(Day::DAY_NAMES[$dayIndex]);
    }


    /**
     * get month from date column
     * @return string
     */
    function getMonthAttribute()
    {
        $monthIndex = (int)date('m', strtotime($this->date));
        return ucfirst(Month::MONTH_NAMES[$monthIndex - 1]);
    }


    /**
     * @return false|string
     */
    function getDayAttribute()
    {
        return date('d', strtotime($this->date));
    }


    /**
     * @return bool
     *
     */
    function getIsExpireDateAttribute()
    {


        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->date));
        $todayDateAsTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
        $eventDateAsTime = strtotime($date);


        if ($todayDateAsTime > $eventDateAsTime)
            return true;

        return false;

    }


    /**
     * @return bool
     *
     */
    function getIsEventTodayAttribute()
    {
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->date));
        $todayDateAsTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
        $eventDateAsTime = strtotime($date);


        return (boolean)($eventDateAsTime == $todayDateAsTime);


    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    function getAgoTimeAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->date)->diffForHumans();
    }


    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    function company()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id', 'id');

    }


    /**
     * @param Builder|CompanyEvent $query
     * @return mixed
     */
    function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('active', 1);
    }

    /**
     * @param Builder|CompanyEvent $query
     * @return mixed
     */
    function scopeSort($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('created_at','desc');

    }


}
```

I also tried different methods, data comes but paging is not my goal paging

my view code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Mr. Burhan</title>
</head>
<body>

{{$events->total()}} adet bulundu
<ul>

    @foreach( $events as $value )
            <li>{{$value}}</li>
    @endforeach

</ul>
{{$events->appends(request()->all())->render()}}


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should use raw query. Otherwise re architect your models..

Comment: ı have more then one relationship ....

Comment: In raw query for join you only need the foreign key columns. If you dont understand then post your database tables, i will show you the example.